# NSMutableArray crashes or have 0 data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to use a mutable array to hold data, and edit it as my program uses it.

```
NSMutableArray* array;
NSNumber *a = 1;
NSNumber *b = 0;
NSNumber *c = 3;
```

These are the ways i tried to define array:

Method 1:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject: a];
[array addObject: b];
[array addObject: c];

//result - crashes
```

Method 2:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: a, b, c, nil];

//result - [array count] returns 0
```

Method 3:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: a, b, c, nil];

//result - crash
```

It seems that if I do `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` It would cause crash, I'm not exactly sure if that is the line that causes the crash though.

How do i solve this?

Comment: What errors/warnings does Xcode show?

Comment: replace like this: `NSNumber *a = @1;`

Comment: What Desdenova said. `1` is not a valid "pointer to `NSNumber`", so it is not legal to assign it to `a`. The compiler should be screaming at you about that. Don't ignore it. You can take that integer and wrap it or "box" it in an `NSNumber` by prefixing it with the `@` character. Or the old way would be `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`.

Comment: @KenThomases, the compiler does not should screaming about assigning any int to object in non ARC.

Comment: @Desdenova I did, with method 2, [array count] still returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Initialize NSNumber objects, e.g.:

   ```
   a = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
   b = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:2];
   c = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:3];
   ```
2. Then either method:

   ```
   array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: a, b, c, nil];
   ```

*or*

```
[array addObject: a];
[array addObject: b];
[array addObject: c];
```

Comment: Works perfectly with method 2. [array count] returns 3 and everything works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber* foo = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4];
```

or

```
NSNumber* foo = @(4);
```

then its add into the nsmutabelarray.
may be this help you.

Comment: He clearly wants number objects in his array. You've created an array of string objects with what were his variable names. I don't think that helps.

Comment: using Method 2, the result remains the same. No crash, but [array count] = 0